# hide my entire website with login from htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to "hide" my website with a login and password with the htaccess and htpasswd file?

So that i can only see the index only if I prompt my user and password?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You must use some like this in your .htacess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

You can use this online generator to create your htpasswd file:
http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Take care: /path/to/.htpasswd need to be absolute path